# XPages 500 / 404 error

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpinc

[edited 7/25/18]

I'm running into an issue at work with XPages that's making me pull my hair out.
I keep getting a 500 error followed by a 404 error seemingly at random and can't reproduce the error but it happens quite often.
I'm sure most people are running their XPages on the web so nobody runs into this but my application only runs in the notes client since the server is not web accessible for security reasons.
I would very much like to use XPages in the notes client only but I can't have this behavior happening on production databases.
I've tried including as much detail as I can think of below but let me know if I can clarify anything to help solve this issue.

1. Notes client and server both running v9
2. Server is not web accessible
3. Application will only be ran in XPiNC
4. The application will work sometimes then stops working for no apparent reason.
5. The issue happens on any database, even with a blank XPage so it's not code related.
6. Clean build has no affect.
7. If I simply open the application in designer it runs perfectly. I don't need to do a page preview or anything, just simply having the
   application open in designer makes it work.
8. The latest time this happened the sequence of events was: Open application, did some work, waited a period of time (maybe
   30min-1hr), try to navigate to another page, gives error 500, closed
   app, reopened app, gives 404, waited another period of time (maybe
   30min), reopened app, works fine. See below trace results for more
   detail.
9. There have been other instances where the app just starts off with 500/404.
10. I tried using a keep session alive code running but has no effect.
11. I have other XPage applications on a different server that is web accessible and works perfectly on a web browser.
12. Issue has been happening since v8.5.2

Trace:

```
10:59:48.547 229 SEVERE com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment doService

CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.websrv.servlets.DispatcherServlet.service(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(Unknown Source)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.pvc.webhttpservice.BridgeServlet.service(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.pvc.internal.webcontainer.VirtualHost.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.http.HttpConnection.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

___________

10:59:48.720 229 SEVERE CLFAD0256E: Dispatcher Servlet Problem - java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    javax.servlet.ServletException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(Unknown Source)
            at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(Unknown Source)
            at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(Unknown Source)
            at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.websrv.servlets.DispatcherServlet.service(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(Unknown Source)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source)
            at com.ibm.pvc.webhttpservice.BridgeServlet.service(Unknown Source)
            at com.ibm.pvc.internal.webcontainer.VirtualHost.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
            at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.http.HttpConnection.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(Unknown Source)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(Unknown Source)
            at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

___________

11:00:30.327 226 SEVERE com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.websrv.servlets.DispatcherServlet service CLFAD0256E: Dispatcher Servlet Problem - Error opening the database 'server!!database.nsf'

com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.util.PageNotFoundException: Error opening the database 'server!!database.nsf'

at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.websrv.servlets.DispatcherServlet.service(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(Unknown Source)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.pvc.webhttpservice.BridgeServlet.service(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.pvc.internal.webcontainer.VirtualHost.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.http.HttpConnection.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: "java.lang.StackOverflowError" - seems you made infinite recursion. "stops working for no apparent reason" - possibly related to build issue, double check conflicting design element names.

Comment: I'm not sure how an infinite recursion would happen. It happens even on a blank XPage without any code. As far as conflicting design element names, none of the elements have the same name. I don't think designer will even allow you to have that but maybe you're referring to something else. The most important thing I'm seeing so far is #7 on the list which may give some clue to the issue. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

if this is a timeout issue, in xsp properties window there are options about application and  session timeout. default is 30 minutes (even if blank)

you can set it a bigger value (i am using 300 minutes)

Comment: I actually have it set to 600 already. I too thought that may be the issue at first but currently don't suspect it to be a timeout issue. I even added some js code to keep the session alive just to test. Thanks for the suggestion though.